# make build fail if there are warnings, YAML

Tags: azure, build, yaml, warnings, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure pipeline for my Team's project.
we defined A pipeline (YAML) when checking in to the server.
there is a way to make the pipeline to be failed if there are some warnings from the .NET build task?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with R Jain. The `Build Quality Checks` task could meet your requirements.

I would like to share **another method** to fail the build task when the warning exists.

You could directly add the agrument:`/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"` to the Build Task.

For example:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"  '
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  enabled: false
```

[image]

Result:

[image: Result]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the below task. There is an option to define variance or a fixed threshold for warnings as well as you can put checks for code coverage.

[Build Quality Check](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks)